# How does Spark run on a single machine?

Tags: apache-spark

I running a Spark job for 6GB of data and it ran in a minute, I am aware that spark uses distributed programming and performs the task. I ran this on my MacBook which has 8 Core CPU, my question is does these 8 Cores perform the reading simultaneously and act as 8 node machine or how does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start your local Spark session with `.master('local[*]')`, you'd (always) have **one executor** with 8 vCPU. In another word you would have `spark.default.parallelism` = 8.

[Spark configurations](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/configuration.html)